# Equivalent conditions to be a lax idempotent contravariant monads

Tags: ct.category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$As [already said](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313487/a-serendipitous-connection-between-isbell-duality-and-yoneda-structures), a contravariant monad is "like a monad, but a contravariant functor":

- the multiplication and unit are dinatural transformations
- an algebra is a map $a : TA\to A$ such that 
  $$
  \begin{CD}
  TTA @>\mu_A>> TA @. A @>\eta_A>> TA\\
  @ATaAA @VVaV @| @VVaV\\
  TA @>>a> A @. A @=A
  \end{CD}
  $$ are commutative (in whatever sense adapts to the canonical wanna-be example of these structure, the presheaf construction, where moreover $\mu=T\eta$).

I've been persuaded, though, that not all equivalent conditions for $T$ to be a [lax-idempotent 2-monad can hold](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lax-idempotent+2-monad). For example, I don't see why the presheaf construction yields a morphism $b\Rightarrow f . a .Tf$ for a pair of $T$-algebras (=total categories). It is neverthelesee true that these two conditions hold:

1. $a\dashv \eta_A$ for every $T$-algebra $a : TA\to A$.
2. $\mu_A\dashv \eta_{TA}$ for every object $A$.

For a generic covariant lax-idempotent monad, they're equivalent. Here, they both hold for $T=[\,\_^o, Set]$, and it's easy to see that in general 1 implies 2 (simply because free algebras $(TA,\mu_A)$ are algebras); but the proof of the converse implication can't probably be adapted to the case of a contravariant monad.

> Is it still true that $1\iff 2$?

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps not immediately clear what you mean in requiring the unit $\eta$ to be "dinatural", and indeed it won't be dinatural in the strict sense under the only reasonable interpretation I see. It does however carry "lax dinatural" structure. Let's first work through this.

If $F, G: C^{op} \times C \to D$ are two functors, then a dinatural transformation from $F$ to $G$ consists of a family of maps $\theta_c: F(c, c) \to G(c, c)$ such that for all $f: c \to c'$, the hexagon

$$\begin{array}{l}
F(c', c) & \stackrel{F(f, c)}{\to} & F(c, c) & \stackrel{\theta_c}{\to} & G(c, c) \\ 
\downarrow \; F(c', f) & & & & \downarrow \; G(c, f) \\ 
F(c', c') & \underset{\theta_{c'}}{\to} & G(c', c') & \underset{G(f, c')}{\to} & G(c, c')
\end{array}$$

commutes. Now of course $1_C: C \to C$ and $T: C^{op} \to C$ don't have the required form, so we have to massage them into shape: put

$$F = \left(C^{op} \times C \stackrel{\pi_2}{\to} C \stackrel{1_C}{\to} C\right)$$

$$G = \left(C^{op} \times C \stackrel{\pi_1}{\to} C^{op} \stackrel{T}{\to} C\right)$$

Then $F(c, c) = c, G(c, c) = Tc$, and the unit map components $\eta_c: c \to Tc$, if it is to yield a dinatural transformation $(\eta_c: F(c, c) \to G(c, c))_{c \in Ob(C)}$ from $F$ to $G$, would have to render the square

$$\begin{array}{l}
c & \stackrel{\eta_c}{\to} & Tc \\ 
\downarrow\; f & & \uparrow\; Tf \\
c' & \underset{\eta_{c'}}{\to} & Tc'
\end{array}$$

commutative. Of course it doesn't in your examples, but there is in the free cocompletion example a lax dinaturality structure

$$\begin{array}{l}
c & \stackrel{\eta_c}{\to} & Tc \\ 
\downarrow\; f & \Downarrow \; \hat{\eta_f} & \uparrow\; Tf \\
c' & \underset{\eta_{c'}}{\to} & Tc'
\end{array}$$

In the free cocompletion example, $\eta_c$ is the Yoneda embedding on a category $c$ and this 2-cell $\hat{\eta_f}$ is the evident natural transformation $\hom(-, c) \to \hom(f-, fc)$ attached to a functor $f$. I tend to associate this with a covariant 2-functor $T_!: C \to C$ such that $T_! f \dashv Tf$ for 1-cells $f$; this $T_!$ defines a relative pseudomonad, and an actual pseudomonad if we are working for example in a Yoneda structure in which all 1-cells are admissible. In any case, $\eta: 1_C \to T_!$ will be the unit, a strong natural transformation so that for 1-cells $f: c \to c'$ we have a structural isomorphism $\eta_f: T_! f \circ \eta_c \cong \eta_{c'} \circ f$, and the lax dinaturality constraint is mated to $\eta_f$ via the adjunction $T_! f \dashv Tf$:

$$\frac{T_!f \circ \eta_c \overset{\eta_f}{\to} \eta_{c'} \circ f}{\eta_c \underset{\hat{\eta_f}}{\to} Tf \circ \eta \circ f}$$

Let's consider the (co?)lax dinatural structure on the multiplication side. Morally, in our example, this should again arise through a mating process where a map $f: A \to B$ is a $T_!$-algebra map if there is a coherent isomorphism $\varepsilon_f: f \circ a \cong b \circ T_! f$. This mates to a 2-cell

$$\hat{\varepsilon_f}: f \circ a \circ T f \to b$$

which is different from what you were predicting above. (Morally, a $T_!$-algebra map $f:A \to B$ in our canonical example is a left adjoint, say $f \dashv g: B \to A$, and then the 2-cell $\hat{\varepsilon_f}$ is just the mate via taking left adjoints of the 2-cell $\hat{\eta_g}: \eta_B \to Tg \circ \eta_A \circ g$.) If we take $f = T\eta_c: TTc \to Tc$, then the lax 2-cell for the multiplication takes the form

$$T\eta_c \circ T\eta_{Tc} \circ TT\eta_c \to T\eta_c$$

and the lax constraint in this case turns out to be an isomorphism.

You haven't really said what (you think) a lax idempotent (unidetermined) *contramonad* is. We know what an ordinary lax idempotent covariant monad is; here $T_!$ plays that role. There are actually a number of details which need to be made precise (and which you haven't made precise in your recent posts). My advice would be to use $T_!$ together with mating procedures as a temporary crutch, carefully translating algebras and lax idempotence of $T_!$ into "$T_!$-free form" (i.e., $T$-only form), but the calculations given above suggest that you may have gotten (or guessed) wrong some of the directions of structural 2-cells. Once you get all this straight, then it seems very plausible that you could prove an analogue of (1) $\Leftrightarrow$ (2).

Comment: While I was waiting for an answer to this question I persuaded myself that it's really a good idea to follow your final advice; it's all about using the monad structure of $T_!$ instead of searching for a really convoluted alternative structure for $T$. I will toroughly read your comment tomorrow to test it against my current intuition, but I must say thank you for taking the time to write in such detail!

Comment: For the moment, I find a bit counterintuitive that even if the adjunction $T_!f \dashv Tf$ exists, the left adjoint is the image of $f$ under a monad, and $T$ does not have any interesting property. I am really tempted to ignore the problem and _define_ a "contramonad" as a functor $T : C^{coop}\to C$ such that each $\forall f : \exists T_!f \dashv Tf$ and $T_!$ is a monad. Do you know if these objects (functors -not monads anymore- with the property that each $Tf$ has an adjoint) have been studied under a precise name?

Comment: Not sure. But I thought you said in your first of three posts that you had examples where this adjointness didn't hold (which was why you were slightly shying away from the suggestions in my answer there)? If so, then it seems it would be worthwhile to see where this bit of centipede mathematics takes you. I'm slightly curious myself...

Comment: For example, presheaf constructions of Yoneda structures $P$ satisfy this property when $A\mapsto PA$ really acts as a cocompletion. Some don't (and even though they are uninteresting, they exist anyway). Now, if you ask me "are you sure these uninteresting YS don't fit in your picture for maybe another reason?" my answer is: I'm not :-) but I add assumptions one at a time.